# Error: Package: 1:npm-3.10.10-1.6.17.1.1.el7.x86_64

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, yum, node.js

I got this what looks like a node problem when I try to update CentOS7.  Could be kernel, this is when I get confused.

```
[root@orcacomputers orca]# yum install npm
Package 1:npm-3.10.10-1.6.17.1.1.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version Nothing to do
```

Okay fine so

```
sudo yum update
Error: Package: 1:npm-3.10.10-1.6.17.1.1.el7.x86_64 

(@epel)
  Requires: nodejs = 1:6.17.1-1.el7
           Removing: 1:nodejs-6.17.1-1.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
               nodejs = 1:6.17.1-1.el7
           Updated By: 2:nodejs-12.20.0-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
               nodejs = 2:12.20.0-1nodesource
           Available: 2:nodejs-12.0.0-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
               nodejs = 2:12.0.0-1nodesource
           Available: 2:nodejs-12.1.0-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
               nodejs = 2:12.1.0-1nodesource
           Available: 2:nodejs-12.2.0-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
               nodejs = 2:12.2.0-1nodesource
           Available: 2:nodejs-12.3.0-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
```

I did run `sudo yum update --skip-broken` and was able to update and restart. However, this nodesource error is still here.

I just opened Thunderbird and saw this cron job error in an email.  Requires nodejs

```
/etc/cron.daily/0yum-daily.cron:

Failed to check for updates with the following error message: 
Failed to build transaction: 1:npm-3.10.10-1.6.17.1.1.el7.x86_64 requires nodejs = 1:6.17.1-1.el7
/etc/cron.daily/yum.cron:

Error: Package: 1:npm-3.10.10-1.6.17.1.1.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
           Requires: nodejs = 1:6.17.1-1.el7
           Removing: 1:nodejs-6.17.1-1.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
               nodejs = 1:6.17.1-1.el7

[orca@orcacomputers public_html]$ node -v
v6.17.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled npm and I was able to update centos.